# Laravel 5 and Lavacharts

Tags: charts, laravel-5, render

I'm trying to implement LavaCharts on Laravel 5 but have no idea how to render it. Trying to follow the documentation but it doesn't work on my part.

Though not sure how to display it in View. Followed this but not working http://lavacharts.com/#example-donut. Am I missing something? How do I call this function in the view?

Here's my Controller

```
public function getPie () {
    $reasons = Lava::DataTable();
    $reasons->addStringColumn('Reasons')
    ->addNumberColumn('Percent')
    ->addRow(array('Check Reviews', 5))
    ->addRow(array('Watch Trailers', 2))
    ->addRow(array('See Actors Other Work', 4))
    ->addRow(array('Settle Argument', 89));

    $donutchart = Lava::DonutChart('IMDB')
               ->setOptions(array(
                 'datatable' => $reasons,
                 'title' => 'Reasons I visit IMDB'
               ));
    return $donutchart;
}
```

Here's my View

```
<div id="chart-div"></div>
@donutchart('IMDB', 'chart-div')
```

Comment: I would suggest reading the laravel documentation on views.

Comment: Nothing wrong with his view, because that's how he supposed to pass the variable controller to view from the documentation. @David Alrdrin. What is the error that you got ?

Comment: Change this line from   $donutchart = Lava::DonutChart('IMDB') to   $donutchart = \Lava::DonutChart('IMDB')

Answer (score 5):

Here's what I did to make your code work in Laravel 5.

```
public function getPie()
{
    $lava = new Lavacharts;

    $reasons = $lava->DataTable();

    $reasons->addStringColumn('Reasons')
            ->addNumberColumn('Percent')
            ->addRow(array('Check Reviews', 5))
            ->addRow(array('Watch Trailers', 2))
            ->addRow(array('See Actors Other Work', 4))
            ->addRow(array('Settle Argument', 89));


    $donutchart = $lava->DonutChart('IMDB', $reasons, [
                    'title' => 'Reasons I visit IMDB'
                ]);


    return view('welcome', [
              'lava'      => $lava
          ]);
}
```

In your view

```
    <div id="chart-div"></div>
      {!! $lava->render('DonutChart', 'IMDB', 'chart-div') !!}
```

Comment: I would just like to offer the suggestion that when providing a code solution, try to be more complete with the code example. By not providing the use statements, more novice programmers that might use your answer as a learning aid will not know the correct use statements. The fact that you're using the Lavacharts class would mean that the controller should, at the very least, possess a 'use Lavacharts;' line. This is pertinent information for folks.

Answer (score 0):

```
public function getPie()
{
    $lava = new Lavacharts;

    $reasons = \Lava::DataTable();

    $reasons->addStringColumn('Reasons')
            ->addNumberColumn('Percent')
            ->addRow(array('Check Reviews', 5))
            ->addRow(array('Watch Trailers', 2))
            ->addRow(array('See Actors Other Work', 4))
            ->addRow(array('Settle Argument', 89));


    $donutchart = \Lava::DonutChart('IMDB', $reasons, [
                    'title' => 'Reasons I visit IMDB'
                ]);


    return view('welcome');
}
```

> In your view:

```
<div id="chart-div"></div>
<?= Lava::render('DonutChart', 'IMDB', 'chart-div') ?>
```

Comment: How do I do it in Laravel 4.2?